# How can I get Highstock tooltip to animate like Highcharts?

Tags: animation, tooltip, highcharts

I haven't seen this question asked before, but Highcharts has a distinct animation with its tooltip where moving a mouse over a point causes a nice smooth slide, whereas the tooltip for Highstock is jarring and abrupt with no animation in between point mouseovers.

Is there a way to make my highstock chart have the same animation as the Highchart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable split option, which is enable by default in Highstock. The animation is not implemented for splitted tooltip.

```
tooltip: {
    split: false
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/65ngtvqd/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.split